# How to get WebDriver using Python to delete an existing value in the table of a confluence page?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, confluence

Here's what the HTML code looks like for a confluence page:

```
tbody
  tr
    td
      some text here


  tr
    td some text here

  tr 
    td 
      <span>some text here</span>
```

If I click on a  element and then do a send_keys("XYZ") then all that goes into the middle of the existing text. For example, it can result in any of the following:

```
soXYZme text here
some tXYZext here
soXYZme text hXYZere
```

I've also tried double-clicking on the  element but that doesn't work properly either. That deletes some part of the existing text only.

How do I clear the existing value in the td element knowing that there's no "input" tag anywhere here. Hence, I cannot use WebDriver's clear() method.

Edit: Please note that sometimes the  cells will have a blank value too.

Answer (score 0):

I was editing confluence cells using ActionChains. And ActionChains, for some reason doesn't provide the clear() method.

However, I was able to solve this problem by directly calling the webdriver instance's clear function. So my code looks something like this for confluence:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)

#ACTIONCHAINS DOES NOT HAVE A CLEAR FUNCTION
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//td[contains(@class, 'confluenceTd')])[{0}]".format(i) ).clear() 

actions.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//td[contains(@class, 'confluenceTd')])[{0}]".format(i)))
actions.double_click()
actions.send_keys("SOME DATA")
actions.perform()
```